# Requests to test on a device the OP doesn't have

Tags: discussion, questions

What do you do about questions where the OP wants you to test something on a device they don't have? This is a recent example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12476820/testing-jquery-scroll-function-in-an-ipad-i-dont-have-an-ipad

Something doesn't seem right about this. For one thing, doesn't that make the question too localized? Tracing down a non-specific error on a specific web page using a specific device is unlikely to be useful to anyone else.

The other issue is that the OP is asking you to do a task *for* them instead of providing them with some insight or a solution to a specific problem.

Would you flag a question like this, or is it ok?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To me "Please test this for me on an iPad" is not a proper question. Furthermore, the links in that (now deleted) question are the only evidence of a particular problem. These links would become invalid once the problem has been corrected. They would after all no longer demonstrate the issue at hand.

This makes this question only of value to the OP and not to the community at large.

All of that makes me consider this "not a real question" or perhaps rather "too localized". As such, I would vote to close it or flag it if I didn't have the privilege to vote.

Answer (score 3):

Apologies.

I was more than happy to post code if needed. My client has an ipad but I do not, this makes testing difficult and slow. I did find a Stack Overflow article which linked to apparent ipad simulators, however I could not replicate the problem that was being experienced.

I would be more than happy to repost the question or edit the original, I am not asking for someone to give me code which will work, but if anyone has experienced a similar issue then any knowledge they have could potentially help me. Which is surely the point of Stack Overflow?

Comment: The biggest problem is that your question in its current form is only of value to you. Whatever question you end up asking, it should be of value to the community as a whole.

Comment: Just get an ipad if you actually intend to service ipad users. It's not like you are not billing your client already.

Comment: What? How do you know if the guy is billing his client? Or, if he is, whether he's billing enough to cover the cost of an iPad? Those things are _expensive_.

Comment: @PopularDemand not sure about you, but I'd be damn worried if the service is actually cheaper than an ipad. The union needs to address this.

Comment: @PopularDemand thank you. By prusswans logic I will also need Android, WebOS, Linux and Mac Desktops. I could go on.

Comment: Business is business. If you don't have the tools for the job, you are not doing it right.